# How to stop lightbox from advancing to next gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I am totally new to js and stuff like that, but I was made an admin and editor of an existing webpage of my employer. The problem is, I cannot contact a man, who has written the webpage, so its sometimes pretty hard to find out the paths and solutions of problems.

The problem I want to solve is on the page using Lightbox for image gallery. When you click on the first image, it pops out and works brilliant. But when you come to the end of the gallery, you can continue to the next car.

Here is the link to show what I mean: http://bmw-groupm.sk/vozidla-na-sklade/

Can you please at least try to tell me, if the problem is in CSS or script itself? Thank you.

**It is not that simple. Cars are added to the webpage by separate Admin panel, which creates a directory on server, puts the images inside and than the car content is called by some complex process. See the html:**

```html
$adresar[$cislo] = opendir("vehicles/".$cisl[$cislo]."/");
while ($subor[$cislo] = readdir($adresar[$cislo])){
  if ($subor[$cislo]!="." && $subor[$cislo]!=".." && !is_dir($subor[$cislo]) && $subor[$cislo]!="t" && $subor[$cislo]!="tn" && $subor[$cislo]!="mcith") {
 $ext[$cislo] = pathinfo($subor[$cislo], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $ext[$cislo] = strtolower($ext[$cislo]);
  if ($ext[$cislo]!="pdf") {
    list($w[$cislo], $h[$cislo], $type[$cislo], $attr[$cislo]) = getimagesize("vehicles/".$cisl[$cislo]."/".$subor[$cislo]);
    
    if ($w[$cislo]<$h[$cislo]) {
        $iclass="imgh";
    }
    else {
        $iclass="imgw";
    }
$pas[$cislo].='<a rel="group" href="/vehicles/'.$cisl[$cislo].'/'.$subor[$cislo].'"><img src="/vehicles/'.$cisl[$cislo].'/'.$subor[$cislo].'"></a>';

  } else {
  $docu[$cislo]="/vehicles/".$cisl[$cislo]."/".$subor[$cislo];
  }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The images are placed in links, which have the same `rel="group"` attribute.

Change these such that each car/gallery group of images has a different value from the next.

For example, car 1 gallery images will be `rel="group1"`, and car 2 images will be`rel="group2"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an image set and give a specific name. The details are found here in the official website.

[Documentation](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#:%7E:text=the%20linked%20image.-,Image%20sets,-.%20If%20you)

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here (not as an image) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your valuable advice, @Nol4635. I will post the code example in the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an **image set** and give a specific name. You can provide the name in the **data-lightbox** attribute. You can find an example with dummy image links below.

```
<p>Gallery One</p>
<a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/b0a4b0/ffffff" data-lightbox="car">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/b0a4b0/ffffff" />
</a>
<a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff00ff/ffffff" data-lightbox="car">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff00ff/ffffff" />
</a>
<a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ed1520/ffffff" data-lightbox="car">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ed1520/ffffff" />
</a>

<p>Gallery Two</p>
<a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/17a621/ffffff" data-lightbox="jeep">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/17a621/ffffff" />
</a>
<a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0e2796/ffffff" data-lightbox="jeep">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0e2796/ffffff" />
</a>
<a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/616011/ffffff" data-lightbox="jeep">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/616011/ffffff" />
</a>
```

The details are found [here](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#:%7E:text=the%20linked%20image.-,Image%20sets,-.%20If%20you) on the official website.